# Custom scaling of the X-Axis

Tags: mpandroidchart, ios-charts

I have a daily record over a period of 5 years. In the X-axis, however, I would like to display only the years.
Is there a best practice for this approach? Maybe to override some functions from the XAxisRenderer class?

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZmqiR.png)

Library:

https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts

https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart